# Compatibility issues Node and Strapi4

Tags: node.js, compatibility, strapi, yarnpkg-v2

allow me to walk you through some problems I'm encountering when setting up Gatsby with Strapi. Hopefully, somebody can provide me with a solution. Whenever I use the following command `yarn create strapi-starter strapi-test gatsby-blog` I get the following error:

[image]

So what I do next is switching to node v15 using nvm to make strapi compatible with node. The result being that some packages are being installed followed by yet another compatibility error:

[image]

Therefore, I am wondering what I am doing wrong and how to make strapi4 compatible with node without having the errors above?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Node.js v16 rather than v15**. It should fix the issue.

Besides, it's better to use even-numbered version of Node.js, [as they're LTS.](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/)